# Is there a way to ls -l with like a -f option (like tail -f)?

Tags: linux, ls

Suppose I am extracting a huge file or slowly building up a huge file. Is there a way to have `ls -lh` "on" much like `tail -f`, so that I can constantly see the size of the file grow until I decide to terminate it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ls(1)` doesn't have any feature built in to do that, but you can probably get what you want with the more generic `watch(1)` command.

`watch ls -lh` will run that `ls` command every two seconds (by default; see the manual page for details) and show the output nicely.

Answer (score -1):

```
while [ true ]; do clear; ls -lah /path/to/dir; sleep 30; done
```

Comment: The `watch(1)` command already does this, don't reinvent the wheel.